# onDestroy of a service is never called

Tags: android, service

I add a local service to my MainActivity, in the onResume, I did this

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume()
    boolean is_start = isMyServiceRunning(MyService.class)
    if (is_start) {
        bindMyService()
    } else {
        startMyService()
        bindMyService()
    }
}
```

In onPause I just simply do the "unBindMyService" operation.

Also, I add the Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE flag to bind the service, the result is very strange.

1. I can see MyService's "onCreate" and "onBind" with logcat, this goes smoothly
2. When I switch to another activity  or app, The "Unbind" is called, which is correct!
3. When I "force stop" the service in settings, the "onDestroy" of the Service is called in response, that is OK.
4. When I remove the app from the "Recent List" of the apps, there are no "onDestroy" of the Service is called, I can explain it as that the service is not terminated. also OK.
5. What I can't explain is that after 4, I launched my app again, I've noticed that the "onCreate" and "onBind" of the service is called, but without a single "onDestroy" of the Service. Even when "is_start" is true, the Service is created again without an "onDestroy" called.

So what happened between 4 and 5? The service is still alive or is dead?

Comment: Post more code. Whats in  the methods isMyServiceRunning, startMyService and bindMyService?

Comment: smallzhan...i have executed all the cases in service...
i found several things. onething i want to say that ondestroy in service can called once the stopservice() is executed.

Comment: Likely 5 is happening in a different process than that of 4 which may have been killed without warning - check the process id in () in the logs.

Comment: @ChrisStratton I've checked the process id with logcat and i found that the pid of second 'onCreate' and 'onBind' of the service instance is really different with the original one. You mean that the original service is killed instead of 'onDestroy' when the new one is started?

Comment: It's killed when you swipe it out of recents.  It may then be recreated in a new process at some point soon, or much later or when a user launched activity needs it.

Answer (score 1):

you need to stop service to call onDestroy.
Use this:

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPause();
    stopService(new Intent(this,MyService.class));
}
```

Comment: Yes, I know that with a service started by 'startService' and 'bindService', I must destroy it with 'unBind' as well as 'stopService'. I think the service is "ALIVE" without a "stopService" called, and I can bind to it later in my app, but what happends in '5' of my problem description is that even the service is "ALIVE", when the 'bind' is called from MainActivity, the service is recreated, that is strange.